# How can I set the selected text color of an NSTextField?

Tags: swift, nstextfield

How can I change the selected text color of `NSTextField`?

I have already tried to find the selected range of `NSTextField`, but it is not useful.

Comment: The highlight color can be changed in the General pane of System Preferences.

Comment: thanks, but I want to set the text color in my macOS program. actually I set the textfield's foreground text color to white, when you select it, the white texts with highlight background color is hard to see clearly. so I want to set the text color to black when it's selected.

Comment: thanks again. as you say. I have tried to fake it by NSTextView. by using NSAttributedStringKey to set the Background color of selected texts. but it's not work good. there are many problems just like horizontal and vertical bounces, handle return key and tab key to fake single line model.

Comment: Did you replace the text field by a text view (the linked question) or did you change the properties of the field editor (the answer)?

Comment: I replace the text field by a text view. and I set the properties and NSAttributedStringKey.BackgroundColor also, but it's not good enough. so I still don't know how to set a NSTextField with THE white textcolor display  perfect while the texts Selected.

Comment: Usually the code in the question doesn't work, the code in the answer does.

Comment: the answer works, but not good enough. NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor can be set to a static color you want, but how can I just use the system's highlight color? user can change the highlight color in system preferences.